# Custom iterator to point to a temporary object (lazy loading)

Tags: c++, iterator, lazy-loading

I have the following class:

```
template <class T>
class IReader
{
    using const_iterator = std::vector<filesystem::Path>::const_iterator;

public:
    virtual ~IReader() = default;

    virtual T read(const_iterator path) const = 0;

    virtual const_iterator begin() const = 0;
    virtual const_iterator end() const = 0;

    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
};
```

It is an interface that is supposed to offer lazy loading of files. An implementation of this class would obtain a list of readable paths and read file on demand. An examplary usage of this class would be as follows:

```
Reader reader; // Reader implements IReader
for(auto path : reader)
{
    auto decodedFile = reader.read(path);
    imshow(decodedFile);
}
```

This however looks a bit strange - As the user of this class I don't need to be aware of what filenames it stores. It would be much more convenient if I could use this class as follows:

```
Reader reader; // Reader implements IReader
for(auto file : reader)
{
    imshow(*file);
}
```

Is it possible at all in C++ to design the IReader class in such the way that it will be iterable like in the last code snippet?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but then you have to actually create your own custom iterator that is an actual file instead of just a path. Perhaps you should look over the design a little, to have some kind of "ReaderContainer" which have a collection of (unopened) files, and dereferencing the custom iterator opens the file (if not open already)?

Comment: Creating some kind of simple lazy resource class would be simplest. You can then make a container of those easily then (`std::vector<LazyFile>` etc.) or then use it to build a custom iterator/container to meet your needs. Solve one problem at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating some kind of simple lazy resource class would be simplest. You can then make a container of those easily then (`std::vector<LazyFile>` etc.) or then use it to build a custom iterator/container to meet your needs. Solve one problem at a time.

```
template<class T> class LazyFileInput
{
public:
    LazyInputFile(const std::string &path)
        : path(path), data(), loaded(false);

    const T &get()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        if (!loaded) load_file();
        return data;
    }
private:
    std::string path;
    T data;
    std::mutex mutex;
    bool loaded;

    void load_file()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this however you want to load your T data.
        std::ifstream fs(path);
        fs >> data;
        loaded = true;
    }
};

// Is a custom iterator even needed at this point? Certainly a seperate problem however.
std::vector<LazyFileInput> files;
std::unordered_map<std::string, LazyInputFile> images; // image name -> image
```

Comment: The very idea here is that it has to be iterable in the way I mentioned. This is a solution but it is incompatible with the way I need it to be implemented.

Comment: Do you really need the exact syntax? You can do `for (auto &file : container) imshow(file.get());`, or juse change `imshow` to accept a `LazyInputFile&` then its `for (auto &file : container) imshow(file);` Why cant you use a normal container? And like I said, its two different problems. You can make an iterator adapter that makes operator `*` do the `.get()` for you if you really want, or maybe create an implicit cast operator.